# Watch doesn't know enums when debugging

Tags: c#, visual-studio, enums, visual-studio-debugging, watch

I'm using enums as column indexes for DataReader columns. The enums are defined in class Config and made available via usings. Example:

```
public enum CtCol { ct_id, ct_nr, ct_type, ct_version, ct_owner, ct_title }

using static DBF.Config.CtCol;

string title = reader.GetString((int)ct_title);
```

This works fine, and I'm using the enums regularly to specify the columns.

But when I set a breakpoint and want to see the expression result in the QuickWatch or in the Watch window I get:

> error CS0103: The name 'ct_title' does not exist in the current
> context

When I replace `ct_title` with `5`, I get the correct value in the Watch. So the debugger seems not to know the enums.
I'm using Visual Studio Community 2022 with C#.

Now I've found out that it works if I add the full reference `reader.GetString((int)Config.CtCol.ct_title)` in the QuickWatch resp. Watch window.

Comment: Does the code compile and run as expected and the issue is just the debugger? Where EXACTLY is that code and where EXACTLY is the enum declared?

Comment: Can you complete the code? The current information doesn't identify your problem? It can only be seen that you may not have a defined ct_title, and this error will not be triggered if you use `5` directly. We recommend that you add minimal use cases.

Comment: @jmcilhinney Thanks a lot for your comment. Updating my question made me find the solution myself. I've edited my question.

Comment: @Stringeater  https://i.stack.imgur.com/mT27T.png I did not reproduce your problem, I seem to be able to query the value directly, is it different from what I did?

Comment: @JialeXue-MSFT Yes, `title` will show correctly in the Watch window, but not `(int)ct_title`. `(int)Config.CtCol.ct_title` will show correctly. Anyway, knowing that the full reference works in the Watch window, the problem is solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution to solve the issue is to add the full reference `reader.GetString((int)Config.CtCol.ct_title)` in the QuickWatch resp.